# How to add an href and img tag via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html

The problem I have is when I put a href link in javascript and also img tag, the image won't display.

```
html='<div id="iw-container">'+'<a ><div class="iw-title">Hot Pot Restaurant </div> </a>'+ name+"<br>"+address+"<br>"+"<img src=/"+image+'</div>';
```

Comment: There is no closing `>` at `<img>` tag

Comment: Nor is there an `href` in your `<a>` tag.

Comment: You are mixing the single and double quotes. `+"<br>"+address+"<br>"+"<img src=/"+image+'` Should be `+'<br>'+addres'+'<br>'+'<img src=/"'+image+'"`

Comment: What is the value of `html` after this line executes?  Is it exactly what you expect it to be?

Answer (score 1):

There seemed to be a lot of typos in your code.

Please see working code below.

```js
let address = 'An Address';
let name = 'Persons Name';
let image = 'https://images.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png';
let link = 'https://images.google.com/';

html='<div id="iw-container"><a href="'+link+'"><div class="iw-title">Hot Pot Restaurant </div> </a>'+ name+'<br>'+address+'<br><img src="'+image+'"></div>';

document.write(html);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use template literal. It is much easier and cleaner to read your code.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

```js
const title = "Stack Overflow";
const link = "https://stackoverflow.com";
const image= "https://streamdata.io/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/stackoverflow.png";
const html = `<div id="iw-container">
          <h1><a href="${link}">${title}</a></h1><br>
          <img src="${image}">
        </div>`;
document.write(html);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you add a code example of that?

Comment: @astonearachnid I edited it :) with template literals you can write html easily without doing all that mess mixing single/double quotes or +

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed single and double quotes and href is also missing. Try below

```
html = '<div id="iw-container">' + '<a ><div class="iw-title">Hot Pot Restaurant </div> </a>' + name + '<br>' + address + '<br>' + '<img src="' + image + '"></div>';
```